# Does anyone know what would cause a shortcode to leave out specific classes when inside tabs content?

Tags: shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I am working on creating an app navigation using a tabs module and the first tab includes a shortcode for a community wall similar to Facebook.  There is supposed to be an option for adding a gif a poll or a photo but when I use the shortcode inside the tab content only the option to add the photo is there.  Just looking for some direction as to what could be causing this ?  Would it be in the php file ?

For further clarification when the shortcode is published it is returning this in the html

when not housed inside a tab it is displaying correctly and this is the html output:

Comment: This is way too vague. You must give an example that will different your situation with a general "my program is not functioning properly" question. Any kind of trail that can help define YOUR SPECIFC problem. If you need help rephrasing the question, I will gladly help :). Good luck.

Comment: Ok I might need help rephrasing it.  Which is probably why I can’t find the solution anywhere …I am using an ultimate member shortcode [ultimatemember_activity] when I publish the page their are two elements that disappear and when I inspected the code their are two <div> sections completely missing from the HTML.  They are visible when I publish the shortcode on the page but when I place the shortcode into tab content they disappear.  Everything else works as expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.